# Tips for adding voltage op amp to equipment

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, amplifier

I have a source that creates a smooth sine wave in the range ±100mV at 1-15Hz.

Due to distances I need to amplify the signal to at least ±5V, and I should also maintain the shape of the signal if possible. Preferably ±12V, but I have been told ±5V will work as well.

How can I do this? An electrical engineer will do the actual work on this equipment, but I need to have some knowledge so I a can coordinate things.

Comment: What is the desired drive distance?

Comment: The signal should carry for about 50-100 meters while preferably making it possible to distinguish pulses at the receiving end.

Comment: Is it pulses, or a smooth sine wave?

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I think you can say it is a smooth sine coming from a rotating gearwheel. One of the teeth is magnetic and it passes a fixed hall-effect sensor. So this causes a ±100mV sine wave at 1-15Hz, depending on how fast the wheel spins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that springs to mind is an op-amp run from +/-15V dc power rails. This will produce signal outputs up to +/-12V without any problems. Most op-amps will do this.

An op-amp can be configured to have gain i.e. it will amplify the signal, and in your solution you'll need to amplify this by a factor of 12/0.1 = 120. This is a fair bit of voltage gain when you consider the highest frequency of the input signal so care has to be taken to choose the appropriate device.

EDIT - I misread top frequency as being 15kHz when in fact it is only 15Hz so the paragraph below is inappropriate for this job but useful generally I believe: -

Gain-Bandwidth-Product (GBP) needs to be in excess of 1.8million (120 x 15e3), and in order to minimize distortion at 15kHz I'd say GBP needs to be more like 10 million to be secure.

You also need to consider what DC offsets may be present on the input signal - you say the lowest frequency is 1Hz (or do you mean 1kHz?) and if you wish to maintain any dc levels on this input that has to be factored into the design.

If you don't wish to maintain dc levels then it may become more complex in that you have to filter "in" the signal whilst "ignoring" the dc. Circuits like this can distort the waveform of low frequency signals so care has to be taken in choosing the correct value components.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. There are only 1 to 15 pulses per second which come from a hall element interacting with a magnet mounted on a rotating cogwheel. If the output signal gets distorted somewhat it should not be a problem, as long as we can distinguish the pulses at the other end of the cable (will be perhaps 50-100 meters)

Comment: @Grubl3r - my mistake - I'll amend my answer to reflect my eyesight!!

Comment: @Grubl3r The hall-effect sensor may produce a signal that is raised at some arbitrary DC level - these needs to be considered so that pulse shape doesn't deteriorate at the lower frequencies. The DC level may be (say) 1V and this cannot be amplified by 120.

Comment: thanks for the information, I think it makes it clear what I should be looking for!

Answer (score 3):

As the objective appears to be detection at a distance, of a series of maxima, whether they be a sine wave or a pulse train, here is an alternative approach that might be simpler:

- Use a **comparator** such as the [LM111](http://i2c2p.twibright.com/datasheet/LM111.pdf) or a more recent, improved version, to convert the hall-effect sensor waveform to a series of pulses, by setting the **comparison threshold around midway** of the voltage range of the input signal.

  - The "Zero Crossing Detector" in the linked datasheet is indicative.
- Use the output to directly drive a **current loop** to the receiving end, e.g. the LM111 can sink or source sufficient current to "*drive lamps or relays, switching voltages up to 50V at currents as high as 50 mA*" (from the datasheet). **No drive transistors or MOSFETs needed**!
- Use **just a resistor** on this current loop, at the receiving end, to read the pulses back as voltage pulses.

This [Current Loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_loop) is a robust, standard long distance signaling mechanism used in industrial systems, such as the 4-20mA and 10-50mA systems. From the WikiPEdia page, "*Current loops can be used over moderately long distances (tens of kilometres), and can be interfaced with optically isolated links.*".

The current loop mechanism is less sensitive to interference than any comparable voltage transmission solution, and the **single-IC sense-and-transmit solution** described above is hard to beat.

Comment: @AnindoGosh that is a very interesting approach. Thank you for the detailed answer. I believe measuring something like 4-20mA at the receiving end would be even better than measuring voltage on this job, so I will suggest this as well.